# What does the \fill command do?

Tags: spacing, fill, vspace

I have been reading about vertical spacing commands in LaTeX and have come upon the command `\vspace{\fill}` which is similar to the command `\vfill`. My question is this: what does the `\fill` command do? Can it be placed outside the argument to some other command like `\vspace`? If not, is this because it defines a kind of "variable" version of a length like `\baselineskip`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\fill` is defined as `\skip20` (well allocated with `\newskip\fill`, so the number might differ in different formats and builds), so it calls the skip register 20, which's value is `0pt plus 1fill`. So `\fill` can be used anywhere where TeX expects a skip value or skip register, e.g. after `\vspace` or `\hspace` or after the primitives which are called by those (`\vskip` and `\hskip`). It is the same as anything defined with `\newlength\foo` and then `\setlength\foo{0pt plus 1fill}`.

A skip of `1fill` means 1 of the second order of infinity, TeX has three orders of infinity `fil`, `fill` and `filll`, each being infinitely smaller than the following but infinitely larger than a finite value such as `\maxdimen` (which in turn is set to `16383.99998pt`, being the largest dimension representable by TeX). The infinite units `fil`, `fill` and `filll` can only be used in the stretchable or shrinkable part of a skip, so after `plus` or `minus` (a skip is something like `<len> plus <stretch> minus <shrink>` with both the stretch and shrink being optional).

Comment: and `fi` units in luatex and ptex:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, but those weren't part of Knuthian TeX, feel free to edit if you want to add it, or write your own answer (which will most likely be better than mine anyways).

Comment: No, I was only being awkward, they are fairly useless: I  only noticed them recently as they broke one of our test files.